# Flask only sees first parameter from multiple parameters sent with curl

Tags: python, flask

I am using curl to make a request to a Flask route that expects multiple query params.  However, the log shows only the first param in the url, and Flask doesn't see the second param.  What is going wrong?

```
@app.route('/path', methods=['GET'])
def foo():
    print request.args.get('param2')
    req = request.args.items()
    print req
```

```
curl http://localhost:5000/path?param1=1&param2=2
```

```
127.0.0.1 - - [01/Jun/2015 21:35:10] "GET /path?param1=1 HTTP/1.1" 200 -
None
[('param1', u'1')]
```

Comment: Your code looks fine. Did you import `request` from flask?

Comment: I am importing:

from app import app
from flask import Flask, request, jsonify, Response, stream_with_context, make_response
from flask.ext.sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from sqlalchemy import Column, Integer, String, DateTime, Float
import cStringIO
import csv
import datetime

Comment: 127.0.0.1 - - [01/Jun/2015 21:35:10] "GET /path?param1=1 HTTP/1.1" 200 -

Comment: Flask isn't getting the second parmeter in the URL itself. Are you sure you are sending the right URL?

Comment: Are you using curl to make the request?

Comment: I am using curl. My request looks like:

curl localhost:5000/path?param1=1&param2=2

Comment: If you're using curl then you need to pass the url inside of quotes. It should look like  `curl "localhost:5000/path?param1=1&param2=2"` . In the shell, `&` is used for forking processes and doesn't behave like you would expect it to.

Comment: Wow! Thanks Bidhan! That wasted so much time.

Comment: Lol. No problem. I went through something similar a while back  and it left me frustrated for a long time. I'm glad you got that sorted out. Good luck.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

See Bidhan's comment [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30586601/flask-request-args-get-url-parameters-only-getting-1st-parameter#comment49243697). I was using `curl` without putting my URL inside double quotes.

To quote:

> If you're using curl then you need to pass the url inside of quotes.
>   It should look like `curl "localhost:5000/path?param1=1&param2=2"` . In
>   the shell, & is used for forking processes and doesn't behave like you
>   would expect it to. –  Bidhan A