# Flask request.args.get not getting all params (Python)

Tags: python, flask, get, python-requests

This is similar to the question and example asked here: [Flask request.args.get get all params (Python)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41229710/flask-request-args-get-get-all-params-python).

Not sure if I'm using `request.args.get()` incorrectly, but I am only able to get the first parameter passed through. For example, for my flask app:

```
@app.route('/longword/')
def longword():

    gid = request.args.get('gameid')
    pid = request.args.get('playerid')
    print("param1: ", gid, "\n")
    print("param2: ", pid, "\n")
    print("request args", request.args)

    return "GID: %s  PID: %s" % (gid, pid)

app.run()
```

and my query: `curl http://localhost:5000/longword/?gameid=123&playerid=456`, I am always getting the first parameter but the second parameter always returns none.

```
param1:  123 

param2:  None 

request args ImmutableMultiDict([('gameid', '123')])
```

Comment: The code looks correct to me... For some reason it's not picking up on your second querystring parameter.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Put your url in double quotes like this when using curl

`curl "http://localhost:5000/longword/?gameid=123&playerid=456"`

credit to Bidhan [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30586601/flask-only-sees-first-parameter-from-multiple-parameters-sent-with-curl)